# How to get the value of checked radioButton so that i am able to display them in next Activity in checkbox form?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I am working on a quiz app in which user selects one of the radio Button from each one card (each card contains one question with four options) and when user click on **floatingActionButton** the user can see which has he/she solved on the next Activity. A checkbox below a question number means that he has solved that question.
I have searched everywhere but can't get anything helpful. I am stuck in my project. 
Here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.pratyush.onlineexamapp;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<ModelClass> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
FloatingActionButton fabactsbmt,fabctprv;
private QuestionAdapter qAdapter;
private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";
private RadioGroup rg;
private RadioButton rb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyclvw);
    final TextView timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer) ;
    int selectedId=rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
    qAdapter= new QuestionAdapter(this);
    fabactsbmt=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.sbmtBtn);
    fabctprv=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.prevwBtn);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(qAdapter);


    fabctprv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent it= new Intent(MainActivity.this,PreviewDetails.class);
            String selectedFromList = (recyclerView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            it.putIntegerArrayListExtra("Respone",);
            rg.clearCheck();
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
    fabactsbmt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your test will be submitted without taking you to Preview Activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timer.setText("Time Left:" + " " + String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))) + "/01:00");
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Time Out!!!");
            builder.setMessage("Your Score is" + " " + 100);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
           /* builder.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });*/
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }.start();

    prepareTest();
}
public void prepareTest(){

    ModelClass que1=new ModelClass();
    que1.setQueNo("Question:- 1/11");
    que1.setQue("who is the prime minister of india?");
    que1.setOptn1(" Manmohan Singh");
    que1.setOptn2(" Sonia Gandhi");
    que1.setOptn3(" Narendra Modi");
    que1.setOptn4(" Amit Shah");
    que1.setAnswer("Narendra Modi");
    questionList.add(que1);

    ModelClass que2=new ModelClass();
    que2.setQueNo("Question:- 2/11");
    que2.setQue("who is the firs prime minister of india?");
    que2.setOptn1("a) Manmohan Singh");
    que2.setOptn2("b) Sonia Gandhi");
    que2.setOptn3("c) Narendra Modi");
    que2.setOptn4("d) Rajeev Gandhi");
    questionList.add(que2);

    ModelClass que3=new ModelClass();
    que3.setQueNo("Question:- 3/11");
    que3.setQue("who is the president of india?");
    que3.setOptn1("a) Manmohan Singh");
    que3.setOptn2("b) Sonia Gandhi ");
    que3.setOptn3("c) Narendra Modi");
    que3.setOptn4("d) Pratibha Patil");
    questionList.add(que3);

    ModelClass que4=new ModelClass();
    que4.setQueNo("Question:- 4/11");
    que4.setQue("Nobel prize is awarded for which of the following disciplines:");
    que4.setOptn1("a) Literacy,physics");
    que4.setOptn2("b) Chemistry");
    que4.setOptn3("c) Medicine or Physiology");
    que4.setOptn4("d) All of the Above");
    questionList.add(que4);

    ModelClass que5=new ModelClass();
    que5.setQueNo("Question:- 5/11");
    que5.setQue("Garampani Sanctuary is locate in which of the following places:");
    que5.setOptn1("a) Junagarh, Gujarat");
    que5.setOptn2("b)  Kohima, Nagaland");
    que5.setOptn3("c) Diphu, Assam");
    que5.setOptn4("d) Gangtok, Sikkim");
    questionList.add(que5);

    ModelClass que6=new ModelClass();
    que6.setQueNo("Question:- 6/11");
    que6.setQue(" Entomology studies what?");
    que6.setOptn1("a) Behavior of human beings");
    que6.setOptn2("b) Insects");
    que6.setOptn3("c) The origin and history of technical and scientific terms");
    que6.setOptn4("d) The formation of rocks");
    questionList.add(que6);

    ModelClass que7=new ModelClass();
    que7.setQueNo("Question:- 7/11");
    que7.setQue("Galileo was an astronomer who");
    que7.setOptn1("a) developed the telescope");
    que7.setOptn2("b) discovered four satellites of Jupiter");
    que7.setOptn3("c) discovered that the movement of pendulum produces a regular time measurement");
    que7.setOptn4("d) All the above");
    questionList.add(que7);

    ModelClass que8=new ModelClass();
    que8.setQueNo("Question:- 8/11");
    que8.setQue("Who is the father of geometry?");
    que8.setOptn1("a) Aristotle");
    que8.setOptn2("b) Pythagoras");
    que8.setOptn3("c) Euclid");
    que8.setOptn4("d) Kepler");
    questionList.add(que8);

    ModelClass que9=new ModelClass();
    que9.setQueNo("Question:- 9/11");
    que9.setQue("Indian Player Jude Felix is associated with");
    que9.setOptn1("a) Volleyball");
    que9.setOptn2("b) Football");
    que9.setOptn3("c) Hockey");
    que9.setOptn4("d) Tennis");
    questionList.add(que9);

    ModelClass que10=new ModelClass();
    que10.setQueNo("Question:- 10/11");
    que10.setQue("The Indian, who holds the pride of beating the computers in mathematical wizard is:");
    que10.setOptn1("a) Shakuntala Devi");
    que10.setOptn2("b) Raja Ramanna");
    que10.setOptn3("c) Ramanujam");
    que10.setOptn4("d) Rina Panigrahi");
    questionList.add(que10);

    ModelClass que11=new ModelClass();
    que11.setQueNo("Question:- 11/11");
    que11.setQue("Who is popularly called as the Iron Man of India?");
    que11.setOptn1("a) Subhash Chandra Bose");
    que11.setOptn2("b) Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel");
    que11.setOptn3("c) Govind Ballabh Pant");
    que11.setOptn4("d) Jawaharlal Nehru");
    questionList.add(que11);

}
public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    public QuestionAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.question_format, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ModelClass model = questionList.get(position);

        holder.queNo.setText(model.getQueNo());
        holder.que.setText(model.getQue());
        holder.opt1.setText(model.getOptn1());
        holder.opt2.setText(model.getOptn2());
        holder.opt3.setText(model.getOptn3());
        holder.opt4.setText(model.getOptn4());
       // Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return questionList.size();


    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView queNo,que,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //RadioGroup radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgrp);
            //RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            queNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qNotext);
            que = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.queText);
            opt1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.opt1);
            opt2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.opt2);
            opt3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.opt3);
            opt4 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.opt4);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my Preview Activity.java**

```
package com.pratyush.onlineexamapp;
public class PreviewDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
GridView gridView;
FloatingActionButton finalSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview_details);
    gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    finalSubmit=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.finalsbmt);
    prepareData();

    ResponseAdapter adapter=new ResponseAdapter(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    finalSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(PreviewDetails.this,"Your Test will be submitted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}
public void prepareData(){
    Model qno1=new Model();
    qno1.setQnumber("Question no.1");
    qno1.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno1);

    Model qno2=new Model();
    qno2.setQnumber("Question no.2");
    qno2.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno2);

    Model qno3=new Model();
    qno3.setQnumber("Question no.3");
    qno3.setCb(false);
    modelArrayList.add(qno3);

    Model qno4=new Model();
    qno4.setQnumber("Question no.4");
    qno4.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno4);

    Model qno5=new Model();
    qno5.setQnumber("Question no.5");
    qno5.setCb(false);
    modelArrayList.add(qno5);

    Model qno6=new Model();
    qno6.setQnumber("Question no.6");
    qno6.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno6);

    Model qno7=new Model();
    qno7.setQnumber("Question no.7");
    qno7.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno7);

    Model qno8=new Model();
    qno8.setQnumber("Question no.8");
    qno8.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno8);

    Model qno9=new Model();
    qno9.setQnumber("Question no.9");
    qno9.setCb(false);
    modelArrayList.add(qno9);

    Model qno10=new Model();
    qno10.setQnumber("Question no.10");
    qno10.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno10);

    Model qno11=new Model();
    qno11.setQnumber("Question no.11");
    qno11.setCb(true);
    modelArrayList.add(qno11);
}
private class ResponseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ResponseAdapter( Context context){
        this.context=context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modelArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (layoutInflater==null)
            layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view==null)
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid,null);
        TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tetView);
        CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkboxe);

        tv.setText(modelArrayList.get(i).getQnumber());
        checkBox.setChecked(modelArrayList.get(i).getCb());

        return view;
    }
}
```

For now i have just set those values in checkboxes manually.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

***You can get the selected item from a radio froup. A radion group consists of some radiobuttons.***

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i){
                case R.id.ans1:
                    //may be your answer is correct.
                    //Do existing works!
                    //Save the data to the database.
                    // Retrive the data from the database in the next activity(Intent)
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: but the questions are generated using Adapters and that data should have an index or position,Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Okay, this is a class where the data is being retrived from firebase database and the questions ar beign solved by the users and being uploaded to the firebase again...... may be it will help you:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a class where the data is being retrived from firebase database and the questions ar beign solved by the users and being uploaded to the firebase again...... may be it will help you:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import holder.QuestionHolder;
import model.ExamModel;
import model.QuestionModel;
import model.ResultCardModel;
import model.ResultModel;

public class LiveExamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        CardView alert_card, timer_card, exam_card;
        Button start_exam, finish_exam_btn;
        TextView timer, exam_name, alert_text;
        DatabaseReference database;
        ExamModel examModel;
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
        RecyclerView questionrecycler;
        long correct_ans=0;
        CountDownTimer cdtimer;
        String stun;
        Map<String, String> map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_exam);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        alert_card = findViewById(R.id.alert_card);
        start_exam = findViewById(R.id.start_exam_btn);
        start_exam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.count_down_timer);
        timer_card = findViewById(R.id.timer_card);
        map = new HashMap<>();
        exam_card = findViewById(R.id.exam_card);
        exam_name = findViewById(R.id.exam_names);
        alert_text = findViewById(R.id.alert_text);
        finish_exam_btn = findViewById(R.id.finish_exam_btn);
        questionrecycler = findViewById(R.id.questionrecycler);
        finish_exam_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadResult();
            }
        });
        exam_name.setText("Exam Name: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"));
        database.child("exams")
                .orderByChild("name")
                .equalTo(getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"))
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        examModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(ExamModel.class);
                        alert_text.setText("You will get "
                                +examModel.getTotal_question()
                                +" questions to solve in "
                                +examModel.getExam_duration()
                                +" minutes");

                        start_exam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        start_exam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initalizeExam();
                alert_card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                timer_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                questionrecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finish_exam_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cdtimer = new CountDownTimer(examModel.getExam_duration()*1000*60, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timer.setText(""+((millisUntilFinished / 1000)%36000)/60+"m "+(millisUntilFinished / 1000)%60+"s");
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        timer.setText("done!");
                        uploadResult();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });


        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("questions")
                .child(getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<QuestionModel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<QuestionModel>()
                        .setQuery(query, QuestionModel.class)
                        .build();


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<QuestionModel, QuestionHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public QuestionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.live_question_card_recycler, parent, false);
                return new QuestionHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final QuestionHolder holder, int position, final QuestionModel model) {

                View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(((RadioButton) v).getText().toString().equals(model.getAns())){
                            map.put(model.getQuestion(), model.getAns());
                        }
                        else {
                            map.values().remove(model.getAns());
                        }
                    }
                };


                holder.clue1.setText(model.getClue1());
                holder.clue1.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
                holder.clue2.setText(model.getClue2());
                holder.clue2.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
                holder.clue3.setText(model.getClue3());
                holder.clue3.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
                holder.clue4.setText(model.getClue4());
                holder.clue4.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);




                holder.question.setText(model.getQuestion());
            }

        };
        questionrecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        questionrecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));






    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    private void uploadResult(){
        try{
            cdtimer.cancel();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        final ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
        correct_ans = map.size();
        resultModel.setTotal_ans(correct_ans);
        resultModel.setTotal_questions(examModel.getTotal_question());
        float percentage = (float) correct_ans/(float) examModel.getTotal_question();
        percentage = percentage*30;
        resultModel.setMarks_percentage(percentage);
        resultModel.setName(stun);
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("results/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name")+"/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),resultModel);


        ResultCardModel resultCardModel = new ResultCardModel();
        resultCardModel.setObtained_marks(percentage);
        resultCardModel.setTotal_ans(correct_ans);
        resultCardModel.setTotal_questions(examModel.getTotal_question());
        resultCardModel.setExam_name(examModel.getName());
        map.put("resultcard/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"),resultCardModel);
        database.updateChildren(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(LiveExamActivity.this, "Finished Exam!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (timer_card.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LiveExamActivity.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.confirn_exit);
            Button exit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    uploadResult();
                }
            });
            Button stay = dialog.findViewById(R.id.stay);
            stay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        else super.onBackPressed();

    }

    private void initalizeExam(){
        final ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
        resultModel.setTotal_ans(correct_ans);
        resultModel.setTotal_questions(examModel.getTotal_question());
        float percentage = (float) correct_ans/(float) examModel.getTotal_question();
        percentage = percentage*100;
        resultModel.setMarks_percentage(percentage);
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("students")
                .child(uid).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                stun = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                resultModel.setName(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                Map map = new HashMap();
                map.put("results/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name")+"/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),resultModel);
                /*database.child("results")
                        .child(getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"))
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(resultModel);*/
                final ResultCardModel resultCardModel = new ResultCardModel();
                resultCardModel.setObtained_marks(0);
                resultCardModel.setTotal_ans(0);
                resultCardModel.setExam_name(examModel.getName());
                resultCardModel.setTotal_questions(examModel.getTotal_question());
                map.put("resultcard/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("exam_name"),resultCardModel);
                database.updateChildren(map);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we store values in some variables as an array and pass them through intent and use that data again to light up the checkboxes through intent.getExta() ?